# use GAN to generator mnist,but study nothing

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Recently,I am studying the GAN network,I'm using it to generator a mnisit image,the environment in my computer is ubuntu16.04,tensorflow,python3.

The code can run without any error.But the result shows the network study nothing,through training,the output image is still noisy image.

Firstly I design a generator network:the input is 784 dimension's noisy data,through a hidden layer and rule it,generate a 784 dimension's image.

Then I design a discriminator network:the input is real image and fake image,through a hidden layer and rule it,the output is 1 dimension's logits.

Then I defined the generator_loss and discriminator_loss, then train generator and discriminator.It can run,but the result show the network study nothing, the loss can not convergence.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/home/zyw/data/tensor_mnist-master/MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)
batch_size = 100

G_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
G_h1 = tf.layers.dense(G_in, 128)
G_h1 = tf.maximum(0.01 * G_h1, G_h1)
G_out = tf.tanh(tf.layers.dense(G_h1, 784)) 

real = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784]) 
Dl0 = tf.layers.dense(G_out, 128)
Dl0 = tf.maximum(0.01 * Dl0, Dl0)
p0 = tf.layers.dense(Dl0, 1)

Dl1 = tf.layers.dense(real, 128)
Dl1 = tf.maximum(0.01 * Dl1, Dl1)
p1 = tf.layers.dense(Dl1, 1)

G_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits =p0,labels=tf.ones_like(p0)*0.9))
D_real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits =p1,labels=tf.ones_like(p1)*0.9))
D_fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits =p0,labels=tf.zeros_like(p0)))
D_total_loss = tf.add(D_fake_loss,D_real_loss) 

G_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(G_loss)
D_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(D_total_loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000):
        mnist_data,_ = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # noise_org = tf.random_normal([batch_size,784],stddev = 0.1,dtype = tf.float32)
        noise_org = np.random.randn(batch_size, 784)
        a,b,dloss=  sess.run([D_real_loss,D_fake_loss,D_total_loss,G_train,D_train],feed_dict={G_in:noise_org,real:mnist_data})[:3]
        if i%100==0:
            print(a,b,dloss)
    #test_generative_image
    noise_org = np.random.randn(1, 784)
    image = sess.run(G_out,feed_dict ={G_in:noise_org})
    outimage = tf.reshape(image, [28,28])
    plt.imshow(outimage.eval(),cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    print('ok')
```

the result is:

```
0.80509 0.63548 1.44057
0.33512 0.20223 0.53735
0.332536 0.97737 1.30991
0.328048 0.814452 1.1425
0.326688 0.411907 0.738596
0.325864 0.570807 0.896671
0.325575 0.970406 1.29598
0.325421 1.02487 1.35029
0.325222 1.34089 1.66612
0.325217 0.747129 1.07235
```

Comment: please make your question clearer.as it is written it is awful to read.do you really not have 5 second to spare to add spaces or new lines or ,correct punctuation  between sentences,gosh this is painful

Comment: this is my first time to use  stackoverflow to ask a question and my English in not good, thanks for you reminding,I will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the modified code with the comments where I made the changes. Moreover, I have described about my changes below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/home/zyw/data/tensor_mnist-master/MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)

batch_size = 100

#define the generator function
def generator(input):
    G_h1 = tf.layers.dense(input, 128)
    # G_h1 = tf.maximum(0.01 * G_h1, G_h1)
    G_out = tf.sigmoid(tf.layers.dense(G_h1, 784))  # sigmoid function added
    return G_out

#Define the discrminator function
def discriminator(input):
    Dl0 = tf.layers.dense(input, 128)
    # Dl0 = tf.maximum(0.01 * Dl0, Dl0)
    p0 = tf.layers.dense(Dl0, 1)
    return p0

#Generator
with tf.variable_scope('G'):
    G_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    G_out = generator(G_in)

real = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#Discrimnator that takes the real data
with tf.variable_scope('D'):
    D1 = discriminator(real)

#Discriminator that takes fake data
with tf.variable_scope('D', reuse=True):  # need to use the same copy of Discrminator
    D2 = discriminator(G_out)

G_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D2, labels=tf.ones_like(D2)))
D_real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D1, labels=tf.ones_like(D1)))
D_fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D2, labels=tf.zeros_like(D2)))
D_total_loss = tf.add(D_fake_loss, D_real_loss)

vars = tf.trainable_variables() #all trainable variables
d_training_vars = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith('D/')]  # varibles associated with the discrminator
g_training_vars = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith('G/')]  # varibles associated with the generator

G_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(G_loss,var_list=g_training_vars)  # only train the variables associated with the generator
D_train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(D_total_loss,var_list=d_training_vars)  # only train the variables associated with the discriminator

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000):
        mnist_data, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # noise_org = tf.random_normal([batch_size,784],stddev = 0.1,dtype = tf.float32)
        noise_org = np.random.randn(batch_size, 784)

        a, b, dloss = sess.run([D_real_loss, D_fake_loss, D_total_loss, G_train, D_train],feed_dict={G_in: noise_org, real: mnist_data})[:3]
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(a, b, dloss)

    # test_generative_image
    noise_org = np.random.randn(1, 784)
    image = sess.run(G_out, feed_dict={G_in: noise_org})
    outimage = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28])

    plt.imshow(outimage.eval(), cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    print('ok')
```

Few points you should note when implementing a **GAN**,

1. Need to use the same copies of the discriminator (*i.e* share same
   weights) when implementing the discriminator loss (in your case **Dl0**
   and **Dl1** should share same paraments).
2. **Generator** activation function should be **sigmoid** not **tanh**
   since the output of the **generator** should only be varying between 0
   and 1. (since its a image)
3. When training the **discriminator**, you should only train the variables that associated with the **discriminator**. Likewise, when training the **generator** you only should train the variables that associated with the **generator**.
4. Sometimes it is important to make sure that the **discriminator** is
   more powerful than the **generator**, as otherwise, it would not have
   sufficient capacity to learn to be able to distinguish accurately
   between generated and real samples.

These are only the basic things of **GAN**s that you should note. However, there are many other aspects that you should consider when developing a **GAN**. You can get a good basic idea of **GAN**s by reading following two articles.

1. http://blog.aylien.com/introduction-generative-adversarial-networks-code-tensorflow/
2. http://blog.evjang.com/2016/06/generative-adversarial-nets-in.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my network following your advise and it works, the 4 points is very useful for me, thanks for your answer again. I will read the two   articles.